# Как удалить из массива значение?

Tags: javascript

сейчас я получаю undefined

```js
function delElem(val, arr) {
  return arr.map(function(elem, index) {
    if (elem == val) {
      arr.splice(index, 1);
    }
  })
}

console.log(delElem(5, [1, 2, 3, 5])); //[1,2,3]
```

Comment: Есть же встроенный метод filter: [1, 2, 3, 5].filter(value => value !== 5) // [1,2,3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Также хочу заметить что вариант который предлагает [@hlear](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/367551/hlearn) может оказаться быстрее!

Тесты:
[image: Данные тестов]
[Ссылка на тест](https://jsbench.me/bwl0h9r2al/1)

Мой вариант интерпретации:

```js
const delElem = (val, arr) => arr.filter(e => e !== val)

console.log(delElem(5, [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 32, 45, 99]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function delElem(val, arr) {
  const newArr = arr.slice();
  for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    if (newArr[i] === val) {
      newArr.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
      continue;
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(delElem(5, [1, 2, 3, 5])); //[1,2,3]
```